# Data Fusion - Argument defined in Argument Setter Plugin Supersedes Runtime Arguments intermittently

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Using Data Fusion Argument Setter, I've defined all parameters in it for a reusable pipeline. While executing it, I provide runtime arguments for some parameters which are different from default arguments provided in the JSON URL embedded in Argument Setter.
But a number of times, the pipeline ends up taking the default values from Argument Setter URL instead of Runtime Arguments causing failures.

This behavior is not consistent in every pipeline I create - which confirms that Runtime arguments are supposed to supersede any prior value defined for an argument.

The workarounds I use is by deleting the plugin and re-adding it for every new pipeline. But that defeats the purpose of creating a re-usable pipeline.

Has anyone experienced this issue ?

[Current Runtime Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zXlI.png)

Comment: Are you checking the arguments as being described here each time? https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline#deploy_and_run_your_pipeline

Comment: That documentation is probably old. Those options are no longer there. If one wants to use args from within the pipeline, they have to be left blank

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case, could you share a minimal reproducible example to replicate your issue? Also, if possible the Pipeline logs file from a execution with this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This wiki https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline provides the sample of how to create re-usable pipeline using Argument Setter. From there, it seems like the runtime arguments was used to notify the data fusion pipeline to use the macro from Argument Setter URL. Argument Setter is a type of Action plugin that allows one to create reusable pipelines by dynamically substituting the configurations that can be served by an HTTP Server. It looks like no matter how you change the runtime arguments, as long as long the same marco can be read when pipeline is running, the arguments will be override.